# Angular async problems with local storage

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous

I am just starting out with angular and i am facing some issues with async operations. I am trying to set a class private value to a localstorage key value that will be used in a http request, but the http reuqest fires off before the key can be retrieved from the storage. I am using ionic native storage. What is the proper way to implement this operation? Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
export class EventService {
 constructor(private _http: Http, private _storage: Storage) {
}

private url = 'http://website.com';
private token : string;

getEventsAction() {
  this._storage.ready().then(() => {
    this._storage.get('auth_token').then((val) => {
      this.token = val;
    });
});

let params = {
  "query": {
    "search_term": "", "page": 1
  }
};
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Auth-Token', this.token);

let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

return this._http.post(this.url + '/api/events/list', params, options)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    let events = response.json();
    if (events) {
      return events;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Where do you retrieve the key from your storage in your code and where do you make the http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the http request **after** the storage callback has been called. This is your code updated with private methods in order to make to code cleaner :

```
export class EventService {
    constructor(private _http: Http, private _storage: Storage) { }

    private url = 'http://website.com';
    private token : string;

    getEventsAction() {
        this.retrieveToken().catch(() => {
            // You can log something here, the 'then' callback will be always executed anyway
        }).then(() => { 
            this.sendHttpRequest();
        });
    }

    private retrieveToken(): Promise<any> {
        return this._storage.ready().then(() => {
            return this._storage.get('auth_token').then((val) => {
                this.token = val;
            }).catch(() => {
                // Set default token if storage.get() raised an exception
                this.token = 'defaultToken';
            });
        });
    }

    private sendHttpRequest() {
        let params = {
            "query": {
                "search_term": "", "page": 1
            }
        };
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers.append('Auth-Token', this.token);

        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        return this._http.post(this.url + '/api/events/list', params, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let events = response.json();
            if (events) {
                return events;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch i will try it out as soon as i get home and provide feedback! Cheers :)

Comment: I have one more question if you could help out regarding this code. In that case that the auth key is not found cause its not set should the .then() part still run in the getEventsAction? I am asking this because when the token is not set in that case the this.sendHttpRequest wont run after the .then() part. I have a default private value for the token if its not found(empty string). If this is the way it works is there any solution to this to make it run? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for the help bviale. For some reason the http.post in the api.service wont run. I have uploaded my 3 files to plunkr if you could help me fix this issue i invite you to a beer :) . Many thanks ! :) https://embed.plnkr.co/qYYSosjMz6g150NdUqr2/

Comment: After a quick look I may have failed to create an 'always' callback in your case, try to add the line I added in the fork https://embed.plnkr.co/49EaSVoRYqEHUkaTxtUA/

Comment: Tried that one aswell, but for some reason the this._http.post() part is not called the function that contains it initilaizes the apiAction and params are all there but for some reason the post part wont run and if i look in the network tab that confirms it aswel since its not there. And i dont know if its normal but i put 2 console logs in login.component after the return and one in auth service after the return and those are printed out undefined before anyhing in apiSerivce is run. Is it possible that they are not waiting for apiService to finish up?